EventBased Trigger type Azure Function Failing with Exception- "EOF occurred in violation of protocol"
I have a Azure Function which is of eventGridTrigger type whenever a new blob is created in one of the path in a container that needs to be copied to another location in the same storage account. I tried to implement using the below sample code :
    credential_storage = DefaultAzureCredential()
    blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient(account_url="https://{}.blob.core.windows.net".format(os.environ["storage_ac_name"]), credential=credential_storage)
    logging.info("Connection to storage account is successful")

    destination_container = "raw"
    container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(destination_container)
    logging.info("Connection to container within storage account is successful")

    container_client.upload_blob('sample.txt','this is test data', blob_type='BlockBlob')
    logging.info("File created successfully in target container")

The function App Managed Identity is enabled and it has 'Storage Blob Data Contributor' on the storage account. While the function gets triggered its throwing the below error:
Result: Failure Exception: ServiceRequestError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1006) Stack: File "/azure-functions-host/workers/python/3.11/LINUX/X64/azure_functions_worker/dispatcher.py", line 605, in _handle__invocation_request call_result = await self._loop.run_in_executor(
Please help to identify and fix the issue here.


I have a Azure Function which is of eventGridTrigger type whenever a new blob is created in one of the path in a container that needs to be copied to another location in the same storage account.

Firstly created a event grid topic and then in Storage account created a event subscription:

In function.json:
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "eventGridTrigger",
      "name": "event",
      "direction": "in",
      "topic":"rithwik"
    },
    {
      "name": "rithin",
      "type": "blob",
      "path": "rithwik/rithtext.txt",  
      "connection": "Test",
      "direction": "in"
    },
    {
      "name": "rithout",
      "type": "blob",
      "path": "test/test.txt", 
      "connection": "Test",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ]
}

Here Test stores the connection string, which is present in local.settings.json/ environment varibales:
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=rithwik98;AccountKey=k6xw==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "Test":"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=rithwik98;AccountKey=k6w==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
  }
}


init__py:
import json
import logging
import azure.functions as rith


def main(event: rith.EventGridEvent, rithin: rith.InputStream, rithout: rith.Out[rith.InputStream]):
    result = json.dumps({
        'id': event.id,
        'data': event.get_json(),
        'topic': event.topic,
        'subject': event.subject,
        'event_type': event.event_type,
    })

    logging.info('Python EventGrid trigger processed an event: %s', result)
    test = f"Hello Rithwik"
    rithout.set(test.encode('utf-8'))

Output:
Blob Uploaded:

New blob created:

If you want to trigger for all blobs in that conatainer use below function.json:
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "eventGridTrigger",
      "name": "event",
      "direction": "in",
      "topic":"rithwik"
    },
    {
      "name": "rithout",
      "type": "blob",
      "path": "test/test.txt", 
      "connection": "Test",
      "direction": "out"
    }
  ]
}

and ini__py:
import json
import logging
import azure.functions as rith


def main(event: rith.EventGridEvent, rithout: rith.Out[rith.InputStream]):
    result = json.dumps({
        'id': event.id,
        'data': event.get_json(),
        'topic': event.topic,
        'subject': event.subject,
        'event_type': event.event_type,
    })

    logging.info('Python EventGrid trigger processed an event: %s', result)
    test = f"Hello Rithwik"
    rithout.set(test.encode('utf-8'))

Here in this code removed rithin from previous code as input binding removed in function.json.

Apologies for the delay in response. Thanks RithwikBojja for the above detailed steps. My case was different here. The storage account had private end point enabled, but the same was not done for BLOB end point so this error of "EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:1006)" was happening. After creating the necessary PEP the issue was resolved.
